# Find the entropy of the quantized source

Tags: self-study, entropy, information-theory

.[image]

> $(a)0.4\\(b)1.4\\(c)3.6\\(d)5.3$

Here the probability $P(-4)$ should be $\frac{2}{7}$,$P(0)=\frac{3}{7}$ and $P(4)=\frac{2}{7}$

Now entropy should be $$H(x)=2\times\frac{2}{7}\log_2\frac{7}{2}+\frac{3}{7}\log_2\frac{7}{3}=1.55$$
but no option matching what the mistake i am doing ?

Comment: I thought the probabilities might be wrongly calculated.

Comment: @Lerner what should be right then help me please.

Comment: Can you provide us more information such as the whole question description in the book? I think you suggested that each item in the source is of the same probability, but that may not hold.

Comment: @Lerner actually i found this question in practice book, i don't have softcopy of this.....btw i too think there is something wrong with the question actually probabilty should be given,isn't it?

Comment: Any answer would be correct, depending on what base of logarithms is intended. For instance, $0.4$ would be correct when using common logarithms (and rounding down to one decimal place).  Compare the question to this one: "A box has sides of lengths 2/7, 3/7, and 2/7.  How much does it weigh?"

Comment: @whuber sir,don't we should take the base bydefault $2$,because in information theory I always take base 2.and how will you find the weigh of box with side length? do you mean volume?whats the realation of this with this question sir ?

Comment: @whuber also please tell is my answer correct for this specific question if i take base 2 bydefault?

Comment: Is g(-3) a typo? I thought the correct one should be q(-3).

Comment: @Lerner yes should be q(-3)